# how to shrink pulsar BookKeeper cluster

Tags: apache-pulsar

## question

I add 2 bookie to pulsar a month ago, but I realized it was a waste of resources. how could i shrink the bookies from 7 to 3.

## my effort

through bookkeeper's document, i find autorecover will bring all ledgers in BookKeeper cluster back to full replication while a bookie is crashed. but if i close four bookes in one time, i think some ledger may Lost forever.

```
bookkeeper-server/bin/bookkeeper shell recover \
zk1.example.com:2181 \ # IP and port for ZooKeeper
192.168.1.10:3181      # IP and port for the failed bookie
```

so i think i can close it one by one, but how could i know the recover is completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command

```
bookkeeper shell decommissionbookie -bookieid $BOOKIE_ADDRESS
```

This will wait until all ledgers for that bookie have been re-replicated in other bookies.

Comment: I find pulsar has some config like this：

`# Whether the bookie itself can start auto-recovery service also or not`

`autoRecoveryDaemonEnabled=true`

`# How long to wait, in seconds, before starting auto recovery of a lost bookie`

`lostBookieRecoveryDelay=0`

 how dose these config work?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start check if EnsembleSize >= Write Quorum >= Ack Quorum is true and should be true even when all planned for deletion bookies were deleted!

1. Go to the machine that you have to stop and check the status of auto recovery

   - bin/bookkeeper shell autorecovery
2. If is disabled just enable the process

   - bin/bookkeeper shell autorecovery -enable
3. Stop the bookkeeper service
4. Case one you are on the machine that wants to be deleted:

   - bin/bookkeeper shell  decommissionbookie
5. In case two you deleted the machine but want to do decommission:
   Then you will need -bookieid
   What is -bookieid?
   bookieid is the IP address of the bookkeeper and the port of the service and should look as 10.123.123.123:3181

   - bin/bookkeeper shell decommissionbookie -bookieid :3181

decommissioning is а time-consuming process always use screen command !